# How many days in a month?

Tags: code-golf, date

Given a textual representation (case-insensitive full name or 3 character abbreviation) of a month return the number of days in the month.

For example, `december`, `DEC`, and `dec` should all return 31.

February can have either 28 or 29 days.

Assume the input is a month in one of the correct forms.

Comment: You should probably list out all the variations of the month names that we should be able to accept.

Comment: what do you mean by case insensitive? do you mean we have to accept any case and give the right answer? or do you mean we can specify whether the input must be given in upper or lower case (presumably consistently)?

Comment: For anybody who can use it, the ASCII ordinal sums of the first 3 characters lowered are unique.

Comment: That was far, far too soon to accept a solution.

Comment: i think this would be nicer if input was just the month in a fixed format, as the format now basically requires converting to a fixed case and only looking at the first 3 letters.

Comment: As it stands it looks like you want answers to handle all of the listed forms - "For example, `december`, `DEC`, and `dec` should **all** return 31" - Is that the intention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 9 bytes

```
l4C9@~%R@
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=l4C9%40~%25R%40&input=December&warnings=1&hex=0)

```
l4        -   input.title()
    @     -  v.index(^)
  C9      -   ['PADDING', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
        @ - v[^]
     ~%R  -  ['Padding', 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

#### Or 15 bytes if all input formats are required

```
l43<C9 3L<@~%R@
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=l43%3CC9+3L%3C%40~%25R%40&input=Feb&warnings=1&hex=0)

```
l43<            -   input.title()[:3]
          @     -  v.index(^)
    C9 3L<      -   ['PAD', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
              @ - v[^]
           ~%R  -  ['Padding', 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

Comment: This returns 31 for `FEB`.

Comment: I believe @Laikoni's point is valid (it also returns 31 for `Apr`, `Jun`, `Sep`, and `Nov`) but also think that it requires a little clarification in the OP (see my [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146555/how-many-days-in-a-month#comment358688_146555)).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Well, the OP has accepted this answer, so I guess it's valid?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I would not jump to that conclusion personally.

Comment: I was under the impression that it only needed to work for one form of inputs

Comment: Pyke looks really cool. Is there any documentation on it?

Comment: @EliR It's a simple stack based language. Some info on each of the instructions can be found here: https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/ and some more links here: https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE/blob/master/README.md if you have any queries feel free to ping me in the Nineteenth Byte chat room here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte

Answer (score 36):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>48 47 44 43</s>  42 bytes

```js
m=>31^'311'[parseInt(m[1]+m[2],34)*3%49%8]
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

m=>31^'311'[parseInt(m[1]+m[2],34)*3%49%8]

;(
  'JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC,' +
  'JANUARY,FEBRUARY,MARCH,APRIL,MAY,JUNE,JULY,AUGUST,SEPTEMBER,OCTOBER,NOVEMBER,DECEMBER'
).split`,`
.forEach(m => console.log(m, '->', f(m)))
```

#### How?

These operations lead to a lookup table of 8 entries, which would not be very interesting if the values were randomly distributed. But any result greater than **2** is mapped to **31** days. Therefore, only the first 3 entries need to be stored explicitly.

```
Month | [1:2] | Base 34 -> dec. | * 3  | % 49 | % 8 | Days
------+-------+-----------------+------+------+-----+-----
  JAN |    AN |             363 | 1089 |   11 |   3 |  31
  FEB |    EB |             487 | 1461 |   40 |   0 |  28
  MAR |    AR |             367 | 1101 |   23 |   7 |  31
  APR |    PR |             877 | 2631 |   34 |   2 |  30
  MAY |    AY |              10 |   30 |   30 |   6 |  31
  JUN |    UN |            1043 | 3129 |   42 |   2 |  30
  JUL |    UL |            1041 | 3123 |   36 |   4 |  31
  AUG |    UG |            1036 | 3108 |   21 |   5 |  31
  SEP |    EP |             501 | 1503 |   33 |   1 |  30
  OCT |    CT |             437 | 1311 |   37 |   5 |  31
  NOV |    OV |             847 | 2541 |   42 |   2 |  30
  DEC |    EC |             488 | 1464 |   43 |   3 |  31
```

Comment: honestly how on earth do you keep making these amazing weird submissions with crazy maths stuff D: do you have a program to find these or are you just too good for the rest of us

Comment: @HyperNeutrino The first thing I try is always to find a base conversion, followed by an optional multiplication followed by one or several modulo operations. This one was found quickly that way. But I misread the challenge and first thought that this `.substr(0,3)` was not required. So, on second thought, this may not be the best approach.

Comment: `substr`? `slice`!

Comment: My trivial approach is only <s>2</s> 3 bytes longer so it might not be optimal anymore because of that, but still very impressive :)

Comment: Sorry @Arnauld, i beat you using Javascript `Date`s ([link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146593/70894))

Comment: @HermanLauenstein For the record, date built-ins [were originally disallowed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/146555/1), so I didn't even try. :)

Comment: Someone's edit removed that part, but one of the reasons I originally disallowed it is I was wanting to see answers like this one. I love the use base 34 to sidestep the issue of capitalization and different formats.

Answer (score 18):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>36</s> 33 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @JustinMariner and @Neil

```
m=>31-new Date(m+31).getDate()%31
```

Sorry @Arnauld, abusing JavaScript weirdness is shorter than your fancy base conversions.

#### How it works

For some reason, JavaScript allows entering dates outside of the specified month. The code counts how many days outside the month the date is to determine how many days there are in the month. Examples:
`"FEB31"` → `Thu Mar 02 2000` → `31 - 2 % 31` → `29`
`"October31"` → `Tue Oct 31 2000` → `31 - 31 % 31` → `31`

#### Test cases

```js
f=m=>31-new Date(m+31).getDate()%31
;(
 "JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC,"+
 "January,February,Mars,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December"
).split`,`.forEach(s=>console.log(s,"->",f(s)))
```

Comment: MS Excel also does this.. January 0 is always December Last Day, so =DAY("00/01/2017") will result in 31

Comment: It looks like Javascript only allows date strings where the day is up to 31. If you try to enter "feb 32", it translates to 2032-02-01, and if you try to force it with "0-feb-32" (or a similar string), it just says "Invalid Date". Oddly enough, if you set the day to 0 ("feb 0"), it translates to 2000-02-01 rather than 2000-01-31.

Comment: You might be able to save a byte by dropping the space before `31`. It seems to work in Chrome as `new Date("feb31")` for example.

Comment: In fact you could probably use `+31` saving three bytes overall. None of this works in Firefox though.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>46</s> <s>45</s> 38 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @totallyhuman*

```python
lambda m:29-int(m[1:3],35)%238%36%-5/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHXyshSNzOvRCM32tDKOFbH2FRT1cjYQtXYTFXXVB@oNL9IIVchM08hWt3L0U9dR0HdzdUJRPk6BoEox4AgCC8SRHmF@kEoH7BcqDuICnYNAFH@ziEgys8/DES5uDqrx1pxKSgUFAFtV8jVUUjTyNX8DwA)

Comment: [45 bytes.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHXythQN9pQxwAIjWOjM/NKNHKjrYxjdYzNNFWNzYxVTY1VTWL/p@UXKeQqZOYpRKt7Ofqp6yiou7k6gShfxyAQ5RgQBOFFgiivUD8I5QOWC3UHUcGuASDK3zkERPn5h4EoF1dn9VgrLgWFgiKg1Qq5OgppGrma/wE "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 50 bytes

```
k=>31-((e=k.lower()[1to3])in"eprunov")-3*(e=="eb")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XctBC4IwGIDhez9jpy0wEM8LNAYVIrL0ENFB7TPU3CdrM/r1q0ME8/rwvpNGg8q13A18G4UBpcCHzQNfoCm7hAajK@sUgUlbhTNhQbT@FpxATZibdKcMbSnpq6ys5JswtvpbKxJpY332cIxls/ekyvUhXTT@05cZeHC0qV/E9l4@C49OkBsYE5CeYlNgIrRnGc5irBd4g5343e4D)

-14 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech

Thirty days hath September, April, June, and November. All the rest had peanut butter. All except my grandmother; she had a little red trike, but I stole it. muahahahahaha

(I've been waiting to tell that joke (source: my math professor) for ages on this site :D :D :D)

Comment: @Riker oh whoops that wasn't there when I started writing this :/

Comment: There is a new rule that you have to check for not a valid month and return 0. I hope it gets deleted

Comment: Nevermind changing I'm deleting that part

Comment: I think you can use a single string `'sepaprjunnov'` instead of a list of strings.

Comment: @JonathanFrech maybe; I'll try that, thanks

Comment: @JonathanFrech yup, that saved 12 bytes, thanks!

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##XctBC4IwGIDhez9jpy0wEM8LNAYVIrL0ENFB7TPU3CdrM/r1q0ME8/rwvpNGg8q13A18G4UBpcCHzQNfoCm7hAajK@sUgUlbhTNhQbT@FpxATZibdKcMbSnpq6ys5JswtvpbKxJpY332cIxls/ekyvUhXTT@05cZeHC0qV/E9l4@C49OkBsYE5CeYlNgIrRnGc5irBd4g5343e4D).

Comment: The joke alone was worth an upvote. :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 21 bytes

```bash
cal $1|xargs|tail -c3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzkxR0HFsKYisSi9uKYkMTNHQTfZ@P///2mpSQA)

Takes input as command-line argument and outputs with a trailing newline. The day count for February depends on that of the current year

Requires the **util-linux 2.29** version of `cal`, which is the one [available on TIO](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzcxTyE5Mef/fwA). Also is locale-dependent, so [LC_TIME must be changed](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/38c5PsTT19XWWSE5MUdBxbCmIrEovbimJDEzR0E32fj///9pqUkA) on non-English systems (thanks @Dennis for clarification).

Idea of piping through `xargs` to trim `cal`'s output is from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12973694/8161100).

Comment: This isn’t just bash. Generally it’s sh, but it’s probably almost every shell implementation that supports path lookups and pipes, on a system with cal, tail and xargs.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>32</s> 27 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

-2 thanks to ngn

Tacit prefix function. Assumes `⎕IO` (**I**ndex **O**rigin) `0`, which is default on many systems.

```apl
32-1⌈∘⊃'.p|un|no|feb'⎕S 1⍠1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/42NdA0f9XQ86pjxqKtZXa@gpjSvJi@/Ji01SR2oKFjB8FHvAsP/aUC1j3r7gEoe9a551Lvl0HrjR20TQQqCnIFkiIdn8P80BXWvxDx1LiDt5uoEpnMTi5IzwCzHgCBPH6hYJZj2CvVzBTOySnMgSkrTwXSwa0CIq6@TaxCY559ckp@UWgRm@@WXpebCOCmpyRBVAA)

`1⌈∘⊃` and use the maximum of one and the first element of that (0 if none) to pick from

`32-` thirty-two minus

`1⌈∘` the maximum of one and

`⊃` the first element (0 if none) of

`'.p|un|no|f'⎕S` the PCRE **Search* for any-char,"p" or "un" or "no" or "f"

`1` returning the length of the matches

`⍠1` and done case insensitively

- **Ap**r, S**ep**, J**un**, and **No**v will give 32−2=30
- **Feb** will give 32−3=29 (allowed by OP)
- anything else will give 32−1=31

Comment: The programming language answering in itself.

Comment: yeah that's impressive!

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>52+13=65</strike> 38+24=62 bytes

```cs
m=>D.DaysInMonth(1,D.Parse(1+m).Month)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc5BSwMxEAXgs/kVoacE20DP6xaKoVBxoaAgHsd00JHNRDNZYSn97WvdWq/u8b35eEyQRUgZh06IX/VDLwVjpc7J1@fsPBR8pIiXw299T/xZqdCCiN4dlBQoFPSm43AjJZ/gXBOXlW4SlzcPvehaD7FeefcTtjz2Zjn3bgdZ0Cyvo3VjaYdKXfa@Eu11A8TGqoO6uk0sqUX3lKng6QM0f/Nmdgc8s7b6R23wJXeQ@wk0Qp6g1h@Z2gmuWT9PUO8d48iO6jh8Aw)

+24 for `using D=System.DateTime;`

#### Acknowledgements

-3 bytes thanks to Grzegorz Puławski.

Comment: Does this work without `using System;`? Or can you excluse that from the byte count?

Comment: @Matty That's a good point; now added.

Comment: Late tip, but -3 bytes: `using D=System.DateTime;` and `m=>D.DaysInMonth(1,D.Parse(1+m).Month)` like here: https://tio.run/##jc5BSwMxEAXgs/kVoacEa6DndQvFULC4ULAgHsc46MhmYjNZYSn97Wu7RcGTe3xvPh4T5CakjEMnxG/a14@9FIzOQ8EdRazU5XCp/yb3QLyvVGhBRG8PSgoUCnrdcbiVkk9wronLUjeJy7uHXnSth1gvvTuHex57s5h7t4UsaBbX0bqxtEOlfva@Er3qBoiNVQd1dZdYUovuKVPB0wdofufNbAM8s7b6R63xJXeQ@wk0Qp6gVp@Z2gmuWT1PUB8d48iO6jh8Aw

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 60 bytes

```python
x=input().lower()[1:3];print(31-(x in"eprunov")-3*(x=="eb"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8I2M6@gtERDUy8nvzy1SEMz2tDKONa6oCgzr0TD2FBXo0IhM08ptaCoNC@/TElT11hLo8LWVik1SUlT8/9/r0Q/AA)

Porting my Proton solution

-10 bytes thanks to totallyhuman

Comment: Better than mine heh

Comment: [um](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRocLK2FBXo0IvJ788tUhDM9rQyjg2M08ptaCoNC@/TElT11gLTdbWVik1SUnzf0FRZl6JRppGZl5BaYmGpqbmf69EPwA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: :P builtins are sometimes too long :P

Comment: @totallyhuman oh rly wow. +1 thanks :P

Comment: [umm](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8I2M6@gtERDUy8nvzy1SEMz2tDKONa6oCgzr0TD2FBXo0IhM08ptaCoNC@/TElT11hLo8LWVik1SUlT8/9/r0Q/AA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @totallyhuman lol nice

Answer (score 3):

### [Shell/GNU Date](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Examples-of-date.html), <s>39</s>, 26 bytes

```
date -d1$1+1month-1day +%d
```

Where `$1` is the name of the month.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PyWxJFVBN8VQxVDbMDc/ryRD1zAlsVJBWzXl////aalJAA)

*edit: Thanks [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for saving many bytes!*

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>45</s> 44 bytes

```
L=tolower($1){$0=L~/v|p|un/?30:L~/f/?28:31}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBDoMgEADv@woOHtoTUi@NifEDfgLp2tYqEAQN0fbrFGh62Z3dZIZvrxC6xqpJbWhOBTvvRdl0H7oe@nCStlVZx2ug7eVaV@zNQhi5hAF7mLkBrk3cnsDoZBoTAe7usKAGJSxItcINBUTFceOTZjJEVzxI0p9R@RcwJ3xuuMWS1LE492hIyqkMsZlfKfyDLw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>65</s> <s>63</s> 62 bytes

```hs
f.map((`mod`32).fromEnum)
f(_:b:c:_)|c<3=28|c>13,b>3=30
f _=31
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYzBaoNAFEX3fsVFulBoQxM3RWrAJqYgjYakKRQKZhxHk1RnhtFJEfLtsdN0ncV953B53D1pv1ldD1XwNZSjhkjH2TWi2HkTd1Qq0URcN65VOpmf@9TP3DN99oLJ05lOx959PvUC79EqkQXeeGjIgSNAISxIdeAd7mD2UBn@CFW0sOMwwSJ6wTJcI1ytDT8RbxOTN4TbV2yiFdLZO5L0A/NoZt8cOhKOkuWmViBSGfY4am5Sg@gKLZMQtAMXJxSM3h6KCddE9ViwXF1lSRTdIzTvtfEesebMnLpHqCvddtgw2bEmZwop7cQfE3H6L@aMXsUeLrSsSdUOD1TKXw)

Pattern matching approach. The first line is to handle the case-insensitivity. Then we return `28` if the third letter is smaller than C (number 3), `30` if the second letter is larger than C and the third one larger than M, or `31` otherwise.

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Leo*

---

#### Alternative (<s>65</s> 64 bytes)

```hs
f s|let i#n=n<mod(fromEnum$s!!i)32=sum$29:[2|2#2]++[-1|2#13,1#3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYyxbsIwFEX3fsUlYWhFGRKmVs2QQqgUlYCgVKoQg@M4IdSxLTumisS3k7p0ZrjvHF093QMx34zzvi9hzpy1qH0RiZdGFvellk0ibDM0g0H9MAkj4zx8et6F59AP96PRbhw4CyaPgT/Z9w2pBSIU8g5K16LFEA1RKB1/pC4MvDTOME9esYjXiFdrxy@k28zlHfH2DZtkheX0A9nyE7Nk6t0cOhKBkuWu1iBKO3Y4WuHCQWwFwxQkbSHkCQWjt4dSIizRHeYs11dZEE0PiN07d94htYK5wzvEtrKmxYapljU501jSVv4xk6f/YsboVbz@QktOKtOPqVK/)

Comment: Clever one! You can save a byte by checking for `c<3` instead of `a==6` (February is the first month if you order them by their third letter, followed by December)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 47 + 1 (`-p`) = 48 bytes

```perl
$_=substr$_,1,2;$_=31-("eprunov"=~/$_/i)-3*/b/i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ra4NKm4pEglXsdQx8gayDc21NVQSi0oKs3LL1OyrdNXidfP1NQ11tJP0s/8/z8rMe9ffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9A0OD/7oFAA)

Comment: -6 bytes : `($_)=/.(..)/;` instead of `$_=substr$_,1,2;` and `()` around `"eprunov"=~/$_/i` can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

## Mediawiki Template, 19 bytes

```
{{#time:t|{{{1}}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## q/kdb+, 36 bytes

**Solution:**

```
28 30 31@2^1&(*)"ebeprunov"ss(_)1_3#
```

**Examples:**

```
q)28 30 31@2^1&(*)"ebeprunov"ss(_)1_3#"January"
31
q)28 30 31@2^1&(*)"ebeprunov"ss(_)1_3#"FEB"
28
q)28 30 31@2^1&(*)"ebeprunov"ss(_)1_3#"jun"
30
```

**Explanation:**

There are a million ways to skin a cat. I think is slightly different to the others. Take the 2nd and 3rd letters of the input, lowercase them, then look them up in the string `"ebeprunov"`. If they are at location 0, then this is February, if they are at a location >0 they are a 30-dayer, if they are not in the string, they are a 31-dayer.

```
28 30 31@2^1&first"ebeprunov"ss lower 1_3# / ungolfed solution
                                        3# / take first 3 items from list, January => Jan
                                      1_   / drop the first item from the list, Jan => an
                                lower      / lower-case, an => an
                  "ebeprunov"ss            / string-search in "ebeprunov", an => ,0N (enlisted null)
             first                         / take the first, ,0N => 0N
           1&                              / take max (&) with 1, 0N => 0N
         2^                                / fill nulls with 2, 0N => 2
        @                                  / index into
28 30 31                                   / list 28,30,31
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 22 bytes

```
14L22Y2c3:Z)Z{kj3:)km)
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39DEx8go0ijZ2CpKM6o6O8vYSjM7V/P///zkEAA)

#### Explanation

```
14L    % Push numeric array of month lengths: [31 28 ... 31]
22Y2   % Push cell array of strings with month names: {'January', ..., 'December'}
c      % Convert to 2D char array, right-padding with spaces
3:Z)   % Keep first 3 columns
Z{     % Split into cell array of strings, one each row
k      % Convert to lower case
j      % Input string
3:)    % Keep first 3 characcters
k      % Convert to lower case
m      % Ismember: gives a logical index with one match
)      % Use that as index into array of month lengths. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>32</s> <s>31</s> 28 bytes

```
i`f
28
i`p|v|un
30
\D

^$
31
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPzMhjcvIgiszoaCmrKY0j8vYgCvGhYsrToXL2PD/f6/EvNLEokout9SkIjDDN7EoOYPLsaAoMwfIruTyKs1LBRI5lVyOpemlxSVcwakFJam5SalFXP7JJfkg2i@/DCLgkpoMZgAA) Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @RobertBenson. Saved 3 bytes thanks to @ovs.

Comment: I believe you could save a byte by using 'f' instead of 'eb'

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPzMhjcvIgiszoaCmrKY0j8vYgCvGhYsrToXL2PD/f6/EvNLEokout9SkIjDDN7EoOYPLsaAoMwfIruTyKs1LBRI5lVyOpemlxSVcwakFJam5SalFXP7JJfkg2i@/DCLgkpoMZgAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) - <s>93</s> <s>86</s> <s>84</s> 82 bytes

Variants of answer (showing the progression of time, and bytes for each, with TIO links):

[Original Answer](https://tio.run/##LcsxCoQwEEDRq6QRJyCC2ClbbLvFXkAsxhg1YCZhHCGePq6w3ePDj5dsgdqcnY@BRYnztv/b4G5pRlZ4KNMvrx39NKNKnccEpvaBZGOk1UJTPV99CMcHkIauHauymEo9NKPWObIjgQUcxVNA/8oHv@ebrxs) (93 bytes)

[-7 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech.](https://tio.run/##NcyxCoNADIDhV3EpJnAI4mbp0LVDX8A6xHrWA5M70gjn019x6PbDB386bI3SleX2KhvxNFOVe6YMb9q8zKQNR7FVST4eWmeBffM1TWdAHvpudPVlqnFoR8Rr4BTVqhPdf1CSBjFYIEjaDRCxPOi53/X4AQ) (86 bytes)

[-2 more bytes thanks to my own further testing of the `monthrange` results, with the second value always being the higher value.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKjkxJzUvJbFILzc/rySjKDEvPVXDUKckMzdVr7ikqADE0KiItjKO1VFXTVLXjDaMBWHrzNyC/KISBZC0DsyI/wVFmXklGmkamXkFpSUampqa/91SnYpCixKLKgE) (84 bytes) <sup>1</sup>

[-2 more by using `import calendar as c` and referencing it with `c.monthrange`.](https://tio.run/##FclBCoMwEEDRq2RTnEAQxJ2lR@gJrIsxxiZgJsM4gj19ShYfHnz@aSw01v31qQfmdUNzT77PhTQK0jfA4DTl0J8q3AD3PI2L6x5rZ@dhaT1T5iJq2nYej0AbisHT@MqSSGGHRHwpWGvrG8XHPw) (82 bytes, **current revision**)

---

```python
lambda x:c.monthrange(1,time.strptime(x[:3],'%b')[1])[1];import time,calendar as c
```

---

Obviously not as nice as [HyperNeutrino's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146562/4949) which doesn't use built-ins, but this still works.

---

*Footnotes*

<sup>1</sup>: [Test cases via TIO.run](https://tio.run/##Hc5RC4IwEMDxdz/FEYxtMATxzbeoCIIwqB5CfJhrpqI3mbPo01vn0@/PcRw3fkPjMF2WdhidDxDawSqje4tP7UFPYKLaeUBoEQreaeQKeG0rYtDeNBR69G1PcdYP4nRf17p5HW7nI3E9XIh8dyMwfxN7a3iZRQD/CxjEhk0ZsGkDDATGvftYL6QCEw8OQ@M1vqxIFP0YT8GPFAKLLC0VZxWXRVJKKZflBw) showing the proof for how I'm handling those `monthrange` values, for a varying number of month test cases.

Comment: [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##NcyxCoNADIDhV3EpJnAI4mbp0LVDX8A6xHrWA5M70gjn019x6PbDB386bI3SleX2KhvxNFOVe6YMb9q8zKQNR7FVST4eWmeBffM1TWdAHvpudPVlqnFoR8Rr4BTVqhPdf1CSBjFYIEjaDRCxPOi53/X4AQ).

Comment: @JonathanFrech Thanks.  Further revised downwards by my having tested more of how monthrange works, and also by using `import ...,calendar as c` so as not having to type 'calendar' twice.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>46</s> 30 bytes

```
#~NextDate~"Month"~DayCount~#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n5JYWWz7X7nOL7WixCWxJLVOyTc/ryRDqc4lsdI5vzSvpE5Z7X9AUWZeiYNzfk5pbp5bflFudDWXggJIZ7SSV2JeaWJRpVKsDlwoLTUJmZvrWOScgSzgGBCEIp@Iotsr1M9VKZarNvY/AA)

Will give either `28` or `29` for February depending on whether the current year is a leap year.

## How it works

All date commands in Mathematica will interpret input such `April`, `APR`, `ApRiL`, and so on as the first day of the corresponding month in the current year. (As a bonus, input such as `"February 2016"` or `{2016,2}` also works as expected.)

`#~NextDate~"Month"` gives the first day of the month after that, and `DayCount` gives the number of days between its two arguments. The number of days between April 1st and May 1st is 30, the number of days in April.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java 8](http://openjdk.java.net/), 47 bytes

```java
m->31-new java.util.Date(m+"31 1").getDate()%31
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU/BasMwDL33K4RhkNDGLOS2rj2N3cYOO44dZNfNnDm2seWOMPbtmeMGdtlskB7Se3rSgBdsnFd2OH3MPgmjJUiDMcITagtfm7UWCSmni9MnGHOneqGgbf/6Bhj6WGfikCfxRNrwc7KStLP8cQX3V/LuWQxK0hEWAhzmsTl2bWPVJ/xqH5BUNW5Z10LLat4rKpX6pmvn/ebsAqzOQCoS3AEb0CYME5yVCAWMGOQ7oA/aZDzBkKzKwUyAqU9ZFJUnNQoVwElyS7buci2clCyA8eiNpooBq5fjIL/VF4UIcCj2PCYRS7W63XX1/kqbYp7OXSKeV7BkbFVW3QKD5pjDttzP0XszlVb9v7KY/a1cWovye/nzDw)

Ended up using the same idea as [Herman Lauenstein's JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146593/69583), where setting the date to the 31st pushed into the next month. Java does require a year, so that has been set to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>38</s> <s>33+1</s> 32+1 bytes

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to Titus*

```
<?=date(t,strtotime("$argn 1"));
```

Run as pipe with `-nF`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxBCoNADAXQ/ZziI10oVKRrtbPrPaYYNVAzYYz09k1L3T@eruo@xHBJZZFxpmePrgNtxysZoRwiLAvebCuUlZBkQvtAVuMsId7DEMfpR2u77lYsG29UV/8Nt6ppevfPiXdv5Qs)

Comment: Hey, I don't think you need `.' 1'`, it seems to work on TIO without it!

Comment: 28+1 bytes: `<?=date(t,strtotime($argn));` (run as pipe with `-nF`)

Comment: @DomHastings - so, before I posted, I had tested to see if it would work without the `.' 1'`, but it wasn't working. After seeing your comment, I tried to figure out what I had done wrong. Because I was running it on the 31st of the month, it was taking the 31st (current) day for any month I put in, which would put it beyond the current month. Feb 31st turns into March 3rd, so the code returns 31 (the number of days in March). Because of this, every month was returning 31. So, it works without the `.' 1'` on any day <= 28th of the month.

Comment: Ahhh, I forget about how PHP fills in the blanks! Thanks for explaining!

Comment: @Titus Thank you. I'm such a golf newbie! I don't know why I didn't realize the `'t'` -> `t`. Also, I had to do a bunch of searching to figure out how to "run as pipe with `-nF`" but I got it figured out (I think). :)

Comment: `$argn.' 1'` -> `"$argn 1"` saves one more byte

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>47</s></sub> 43 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input, as month name, abbreviation, or number, from range `[A1]` and outputs the length of that month in the year 2001 to the VBE immediate window function.

```vb
?31-Day(DateValue("1 "&[A1]&" 1")+30)Mod 31
```

#### Old Version

```vb
d=DateValue(["1 "&A1&" 1"]):?DateAdd("m",1,d)-d
```

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>49</s> 35 bytes

```
?31-(instr(@aprjunsepnov feb`,;)%3)
```

Significantly shorter with some trickery.

### Explanation

```
?                          PRINT
31-(                       31 minus
  instr(                   the position of
                      ,;   our input string
    @aprjunsepnov feb`  )  in the string cntaining all non-31 months                                
    %3)                    modulo 3 (this yields a 1 for each month except feb=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 126 bytes

```java
s->{for(java.time.Month m:java.time.Month.values())if(m.name().startsWith(s.toUpperCase()))System.out.print(m.length(false));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY5NS8NAEIbP5lcsOe0K3R9gtGCLgmJPpXgQD9tkkm7cL3ZmA6Xkt8fFVpAePGSO78wz79OrQS18ANc3X5O2wUdifc5kIm1km1xN2jt5W4W0N7pmtVGIbKO0OxVIinK09g6ThXi/pahdt2SNOuKL23hHB/bAJlwsT62P/OctaQvyvLJ3V4kclEmAXAjdciudssCFzC2R8F3TgaMkvwsB4lphXgmxPSKBlT6RDLmbMmXAdfm0VQZBiGqcfs0vtoPXDbPZn591Pz6ZEuxUsMv8kZeqriEQL5@fVqWoipvrOuN4jv8jG6jB7iHOxBHCTPJ19zaTfExdQiovV2MxTt8)

Comment: I think you can shorten `false` to a boolean expression like `1<0` to save a couple bytes.

Answer (score 0):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 24 bytes

**23 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

```perl
$_=31-/p|un|no/i-/f/i*3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tbYUFe/oKY0ryYvXz9TVz9NP1PL@P9/r8S80sSiSi631CSu3MSi5AyuxIIiLl/HSC6vUD8ur9KcSi7H0nSu4tSCktTcpNQirvzkEi4//zBXXyfXIC4XV2euf/kFJZn5ecX/dQtyAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```ruby
->m{((Date.parse(m)>>1)-1).day}
require'date'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxba8JAFITf/RVDXkyQLPjYhwa2JhZCTURrQUopm3isgVy2eyks6m9Pt@nDzHycM4yylRvPj2OcdNcwTIUhJoXSFHZRkiyjeBmxk3D3maJv2yian3xjPgY5L7DOnrDhO/DtzucR@aHwegE/PGOfbVGuXlGUb0izFXLRW6Ec1lSpCTZC1RdwqZrWs0Nue/LWOnD7ZbXBnqShriKFsjbDXxbDz/8hpXqCYMa0bBvDSPitK27d0JvLDdIajYlZTb0hFT5EWCBAnHhb4Pw@PT@YGT417uMv)

Ruby's `Date.parse` accepts a month name on its own. What would normally be a right-shift (`>>`) actually adds to the month of the `Date` object. Subtraction affects the day of the month, which will wrap backwards to the last day of the previous month.

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 92 bytes

```
val d={m:String->arrayOf(0,31,30,30,31,30,31,28,31,0,30)[(m[1].toInt()+m[2].toInt())%32%11]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTbjtMwEH3PV4yqRTRQEtKyCCoKQstyeQIJeFrx4MaTxqxjB1@6rVb7L3zL/liZcdrCIh6IqtSe2zlzPM6lDVqZXfkAzhyKgBIa6yC0ykNtJcLK6gbqVmiNZoXzrA2h9/OyZCf7Ch9EfYkbCiF/Uduu/BHRB2WNL6snT09PT7P39go6YbYgxdaDMiCgsya0r7LsnVoj7wNuQhQaHPYOPZoguAKMa@HxkTJk8SpQLDRRazCiQyCaM2bmRB3QgVguHa5VysvBNgcQKhmiM9QSgondkkLJeWDC1hRWZNlbqogb0fUaJ7c/JdbI0bR8c342AWFkMt7@9K2NWgJJcqg9qzgdly4Kt4VaGGgFcUVF5R1MnzHX6fMESoGvvY/En6GV6WMA0vpAlihZg8yQ3bV1DuvAR9JR5oMyy8oSzjc9kaGTWqPzrNIxWmKxP0aiC8I5v4UrIsFZ/@ifTxpF3UJvvVdLzXwkbmAtdMSCk945sUyZHmtrJIvAs@HkH8Lv0RP/SULay91RuWD5hStimpKFlMlVwBdxmTTgjM7KqC3MpuAt8JEfWzqgeJAWvbkfaJAC7RO7VGKfW1VAWPWx@aEThtTWXkLsD1hD5852CYA0EtuCs6@ETxZtr2h8Bw3IIAInaSRgUqHXKjAOB85AqqZBR8NKc/AjKsdHwml0VE00CWmcZJnD5@CUWeWwyICehPqxGT@ezKrJ7HH6Vfv39Bm/2ZZC@ckvhjIX1bci2A8mjPOHg2F6NOT3ZtN7VfUtTcgX7kA6ui8uMemEMmPhVn4Orxn6xUDnZQ7XHP58CsttQJ/tiD7IxXU3HwIevfw/pkzwDrl/ELvZUT8E9gkdj3OSkDADiQUs27CBxVGc0Xdh@D6NJjBq9neL151wdTua7NUZid4pPdiT@3s0OPzrtBdxFX34He@xD@lis9PWwe6Xxq6P5sPdH@WUxbdkzOTS94JJsmxci1nHvqc7sEgOavkrb89ogsd5CiFyJmgzHp2kCi0N2cm1TOXym@GDMPo7cih5CE27O7E3LCOxytKCzzbb/QI)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 100 bytes

```javascript
(z,v=n=e=b=r=y=u=c=0,t=s=a=l=1,f=p=29,m=j=g=o=30,d=31)=>eval([z[0],z[1],z[2]].join`+`.toLowerCase())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5Pa4QwFMTP3U8RPCU0DbpeWsrbS6@99iTCxuxbV4lJyB9FSz@71S29FHqZ92PeMEwvRxmU71x8Gp/XCVa68BEMIDTgYYYECnIeIYAEDQW/goPjCx@ghxYslDm/QFkwOOEoNa2WKq/5UhW7HOta9LYz58eziPbdTujfZEDK2Jr10iTpZ3LFxt9hkF7diHS@0xvPpE8GN9EzkalNIZKALuLQoCdWRbtfY8cf44LqDpkITneRZiRjYpCOHhBOn4cHZU2wGoW2LUU@UWTs9Y8rQmpC9DTnJdvGfjj3O3bP///dm77Y@g0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Uses [Herman's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146593/58974).

```
´H-ÐU+H f uH
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=tEgt0FUrSCBmIHVI&footer=SLExVQ&input=WyJKYW51YXJ5IiAiRmVicnVhcnkiICJNYXJjaCIgIkFwcmlsIiAiTWF5IiAiSnVuZSIgIkp1bHkiICJBdWd1c3QiICJTZXB0ZW1iZXIiICJPY3RvYmVyIiAiTm92ZW1iZXIiICJEZWNlbWJlciJdLW0) (includes all test cases, footer resets the `H` constant for the next case)