# Days in indexed month

Tags: code-golf, date

This simple challenge is very similar to this one: [How many days in a month?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146555) The only difference is you **yield the number of days in a month given the index of the month** instead of its name.

The reason I ask this near-duplicate is curiosity about mathematical patterns in the sequence of numbers. For example, a simple observation is that even-indexed months have 31 until August and then it flips — but golf that observation and/or make better ones that yield better strokes...

**INPUT**: Integer indicating the month; `1` through `12`. (Optionally, you can accept `0`-indexed month numbers from `0` to `11`.)

**OUTPUT**: Number of days in that month. February can return `28` or `29`.

**Complete I/O table:**

```
INPUT   :   OUTPUT
  1          31
  2          28 or 29 
  3          31
  4          30
  5          31
  6          30
  7          31
  8          31
  9          30
 10          31
 11          30
 12          31
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>13</s> 12 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. 0-indexed. February is 29.

```apl
31-1∘=+2|7∘|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///39hQ1/BRxwxbbaMacyBd8z/tUduER719j/qmevo/6mo@tN74UdtEIC84yBlIhnh4Bv9PUzBQMFQwUjBWMFEwVTBTMFewULBUMAQKGgIA)

`31-` thirty-one minus…

`1∘=` the equal-to-one'ness…

`+` plus…

`2|` the two-mod of…

`7∘|` the seven-mod'ness

> The reason I ask this near-duplicate is curiosity about mathematical patterns in the sequence of numbers. For example, a simple observation is that even-indexed months have 31 until August and then it flips — but golf that observation and/or make better ones that yield better strokes...

This solution implements the following mathematical pattern:

$$f(x)=31-[x=1]-\big((x\mod 7)\mod 2\big)$$

or

$$f(x)=31-x-\left[x=1\right]+7\left\lfloor\frac{x}7\right\rfloor+2\left\lfloor x-7\left\lfloor\frac{x}7\right\rfloor\over2\right\rfloor$$

Comment: What is the $[1=x]$ notation?

Comment: @infinitezero It means "1 if x=1, 0 otherwise".

Comment: @infinitezero [Iverson bracket](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf#page=37) (bottom of page: *So far the notations…*)

Answer (score 13):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/index.html), 706 bytes

```
counting a day,one month<t-o>twelve
i got frustrated doing a list
i do say,o,i edited a list,a month&a day count
in twelve(in December)to one(January)i listed a day"s count,then the numeral months
and once i am ready,o,i think i got a number to say
a number,o,i know a count
o,i say i am thirty if one"s short
i am ready,o,i know a count is not a thirty if we switch it
a long,a short,a etc.i switch
i do think i want a count of Febr-u"ry=two n eight:a case of a month"s age as shorter than the others"s
a day"s a day,i reckon
i know,i am clever
o,a date"s count at min=a thirty-day,or affix a one,i think
i do start&i produce threes if ever i am thirty
P.S.note:i index by one,i receive any-format numbers
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?VVJBbuMwDLz7FUQOQQM4OfRYbPe06GFPC@wLGIu2iNjUQqLj@vUtJdnb9GLLJmc4M1QXZlGWARAcrm0QgimI@h96Dj91ofFODcMQFPo4J42o5MCFihg5qVVdgJSxLQM5zg211GLlOhZu6PKohgUq7ZOdflFH05XiSQPY6KffKDPG9cQFX4gMeUgV26onQ3sCmSeKOFb61KA4g3cEDDhBJHRVjXqWG1T5mEE2CrSobfbv0niTsFhHVZh/WEclM4qodu6zPhOSfIjZ87c5j3DgBFLmfUEXgrSwdh5YbfAYZLBsCpW9SbsLbw01zV33gqL/eUMPb3SN5/kQ11ddAggQD15frAET5fqWt8nEgQA3tdmzxxpcsEdMB4tsC7aunc1MdwvSVC9t8deNdKdoceQepX0LgAoTy@tu8FzuTQTse343Pstpj367G4pRjwz/YnCzLUl9JEo5l8z/GHPz5/L3YuHRCwOLo3e4rhuf6SO@mylZz32Ik4mo@0sfzx9XdJ8)

As noted in the final line of the program, this program takes months as 1-based indices, and can take both simple numbers and numbers with a leading 0. (How's *that* for code comments?)

In pseudocode, my approach was basically like this:

```js
N = input(); // Poetic doesn't support native numerical input, only input as ASCII codes; I basically have to write myself a number input routine every time
DIGIT = 49 // ASCII value for "1"; I would set it to 3, but that would be slightly longer
if (N>7) N++; // this accounts for the July->August parity shift
if (N!=2) { // if not February...
    DIGIT += 2; // now it's "3"
    print(DIGIT); // output: "3"
    DIGIT -= 3; // and now it's "0"...
    if (N%2==1) THREE++; // ...unless N is odd
    print(DIGIT); // output: "30" if short month, "31" if long month
} else { // if February...
    DIGIT += 1; // now it's "2"
    print(DIGIT); // output: "2"
    DIGIT += 6; // now it's "8"
    print(DIGIT); // output: "28"
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you used ```"``` instead of ```'```?

Comment: @A_ Apostrophes are "closed off" in Poetic; for example, `can't` is a 4-letter word. As far as code golf goes, apostrophes are entirely useless. (I'd have used the Unicode right-quotation-mark, but that's more than one byte.)

Comment: @A_ Basically, apostrophes are deleted, non-letter characters (defined as a character that returns false for the `is_alpha()` function in Python, or equivalently that doesn't match the newfangled `\p{L}` regex) are replaced with whitespace, and then the whole program is split on whitespace and its word-lengths are counted and turned into program instructions.

Answer (score 12):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 4 bytes

```
~%R@
```

I have no idea how does this work (actually, after reading the source, I think I do, but Pyke seems **extremely** weird to me) as I simply used the second half of the Pyke answer by @Blue in the related question OP linked to.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6jMTv3/v041yOH/f2MA)

Comment: For anyone else wondering what this does and don't know Pyke (like me): [here are the Pyke docs](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/docs) and this code will: `~%` push the builtin list `['Padding', 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]`; `R` rotate the values on the stack (at least 2) - so with only a single value on the stack it takes the input implicitly and acts like a swap (`Q` -get input- instead of `R` would be more a more intuitive alternative); `@` index this input into the list; (and output the result implicitly with trailing newline). PS: 0-based input with `~MQ@` is also possible.

Comment: Thank you for notifying me Pyke has docs! :)

Comment: Took me a bit to find as well, haha. ;) On the github page it links to ["_me saying how great the language is_"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9619/advocate-languages-to-golf-in/9636#9636), where it at the bottom links to "_This documentation can be found in pure html form [here](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/docs)._" Not sure why this html docs aren't in the github README or Wiki page tbh..

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), 16 bytes

All solutions expect a 0-indexed input and output 29 days for February.

Using a decimal modulo.

```javascript
n=>n%1.7+!~-n^31
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5P1VDPXFuxTjcvztjwf1p@kUaegq2CgbVCnoKNgqERkNbW1lRIzs8rzs9J1cvJT9fI01FI08jT1PwPAA)

---

Using a single integer modulo.

```javascript
n=>30-!~-n|n%7^1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1s7YQFexTjevJk/VPM7wf1p@kUaegq2CgbVCnoKNgqERkNbW1lRIzs8rzs9J1cvJT9fI01FI08jT1PwPAA)

---

Same approach as [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195887/58563) with 2 integer modulos.

```javascript
n=>31-n%7%2-!~-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcVBDkAwEAXQq4yFpE2NUAsL6i5NqRD5IyqWrl7e5u3@8Slc23kzZF5ydBlu6lpG2ZeWi5eRo1wK5KgZCDRSa/@N0RQESY6lPmRVqCgqaJ0/)

Answer (score 10):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 27 bytes

0-indexed.

Instead of indexing into a string, I get the day offset (from 28) for the month from a packed bit array. Luckily all the offsets fit in a two-bit representation, so the bit array fits in an integer: I just shift and mask the offset and add 28.

```c
f(m){m=0xEEFBB3>>m*2&3|28;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1ezOtfWoMLV1c3JydjOLlfLSM24xsjCuvZ/Zl6JQm5iZp5GWX5miqZCNZeCQlp@kQZIONPWwFoh08bQCEhqa2sqFBQBRdM0lHzz80oyFFRTFGztQGRKYmVxTJ6SjkKmjkKaRqampjVX7f9/yWk5ienF/3XLAQ)

Comment: Are you sure this is shorter than indexing into a string though?

Comment: @someone No, it's not. It's more fun though. It probably would be if there were more than 12 months in a year, however! :-)

Answer (score 8):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 3 bytes

```
∂k=
```

Yep, there's a built-in.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//1FHU7bt//9GAA)

```
∂k   List containing days in each month
  =  Index into it (implicit input)
```

Answer (score 6):

## x86 Machine Code, 14 bytes

```
B8 B3 FB EE 00
01 C9
D3 E8
24 03
04 1C
C3
```

This is a straight port of [ErikF's C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195904). The above bytes define a function that accepts a zero-indexed month (in the `ECX` register), and outputs the number of days (in the `AL` register, the lower-order bytes of the `EAX` register). The result is calculated by adding 28 to a fix-up parameter obtained from a sequenced vector of 2-bit values.

```
B8 B3 FB EE 00   mov    eax, 0x00EEFBB3    ; load bit vector into EAX
01 C9            add    ecx, ecx           ; \ index into the bit vector
D3 E8            shr    eax, cl            ; |   by shifting it right
24 03            and    al,  3             ; /   and keeping only the lowest 2 bits
04 1C            add    al,  28            ; add 28
C3               ret
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFdT8IwFIavt19xMiXpYMKYkRgBE6NecOG9FyRLbcvWpHSkHwYx/HVn2ykRJfamp@3z9ny85IIILKu2tVLzSjIKpMYKHvCbXsinRpoacWlg7aM0fo/BrQOqmLbCTMNlWWK9LkuULM26eRXu5nx8NZkUeX6ZQa/H8HYpk0B@L0diSj3pnsk267YTlK5VRxHxz1eSvvikIRsWp5MForjukCPgBpI5TgB1LaUAoz401myscV1WXBumgGt4vHuG/uiXkCQAqJsQBCGXXncsvP8r/HlKuykqZqySh8Hu2zMuibCUwUwbypthfRvHwRDMJfKGRKtGAdJ8x0oDHOaQT902g3ExhcGAp3HkmGijnGiFkuAo9IqdhRprF1CgzuqhG1cGPANvdnpkfuoqi/Zx9FVZ7ov6ICuBK91@Ag)**

Note that we can do the `AND` and `ADD` on byte-sized operands, which results in 2-byte instructions, rather than the 3-byte instructions required to operate on double-words.

The big bloat here is that initial 32-bit `MOV` instruction required to load the bit vector, but this implementation is still significantly smaller than a solution implementing the mathematical algorithm cited by [Adam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195887/58518): `(31 - ((month % 7) % 2) - (month == 1))`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda n:31-n%7%2-(n==1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPythQN0/VXNVIVyPP1tZQ839afpFCnkJmnkJRYl56qoahkaYVl0JBUWZeiUaaRp6m5n8A)

Adaptation of [Adám's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195887/87681)

---

Original answer:

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 29 bytes

```python
lambda n:31^n%2^n//7^2*(n==1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPytgwLk/VKC5PX988zkhLI8/W1lDzf1p@kUKeQmaeQlFiXnqqhqGRphWXQkFRZl6JRppGnqbmfwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
7%É31αsΘ-
```

Same formula as [*@Adám*'s APL (Dyalog Unicode) answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195887/52210), which I've also partially used in [this earlier answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173104/the-work-day-countdown/173126#173126).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9o5OZnr6TwqG2SgpK9n8t/c9XDncaG5zYWn5uh@1/nPwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
7%         # Take the (implicit) input-integer modulo-7
  É        # Check whether it is odd (short for modulo-2)
   31α     # Take the absolute difference with 31
      s    # Swap to take the (implicit) input-integer again
       Θ   # 05AB1E truthify; 1 if n==1; 0 otherwise
        -  # And subtract this from the earlier number
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), 197 bytes

```
0 0 _ * j
0 1 _ r F
0 2 _ * j
0 3 2 * F
0 4 _ * j
0 5 2 * F
0 6 _ * j
0 7 _ * j
0 8 2 * F
0 9 _ * j
h * * * halt
j _ 3 r ǰ
ǰ _ 1 * h
F _ 2 r Ƒ
Ƒ _ 8 * h
F 0 2 * F
F 1 _ r j
N _ 0 * h
F 2 3 r N
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?8f4d81596dcfd7859a1915b575e5df9d)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>58</strike> 45 bytes

```python
lambda x:'312831303130313130313031'[x*2:][:2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRocJK3djQyMLY0NgAiuEs9egKLSOr2Ggro9j/BUWZeSUaaRqGmpr/AQ)

- A weak solution to get it started with an "unanalyzed" solution space
- Saved a few bytes by functionizing thanks to Jo King

Comment: This can quickly be improved to [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI0ldQV5GXg4IwYR6NEgwM6@gtERDUzNW8/9/IwA) with unprintables, or [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRocIqSV1BXkZeDgjBhHp0Rez/gqLMvBKNNA0jTc3/AA) as a function

Comment: @JoKing Good call. The unprintables I think is inventive enough that you can post it as a separate answer if you want, but I've functionized.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 31 bytes

```php
<?=date(t,mktime(0,0,0,$argn));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42JbEkVaNEJze7JDM3VcNABwRVEovS8zQ1rf//N/mXX1CSmZ9X/F/XDQA)

Just using builtins really. Input month via STDIN, 1-indexed.

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 20 bytes

```cs
x=>""[x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXogPEdmm2/yts7ZTkZeTlgBBMKEVXxP635krLL9IAqlDItDWwzrQxNLLO1NbWDC/KLEn1ycxL1UjTyNTUtP4PAA)

Comment: I think a string of unprintables is shorter.

Comment: What is this sorcery

Comment: @Innat3: indexing a string where the "characters" are small integers, below ASCII 32 = space.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>42</s> <s>39</s> 35 bytes

```python
lambda i:(30+(i%2==(i<8)),28)[i==2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc29DkAwEADg3VNYJL0wtFc/Je5JMBARl1AiFk9fk5zt277zudfDY1ioD9u4T/MYc6OsThUnSKS4dQAZOuiYCIdwXuzveFEGoo8otMJcWAhLYSV0wlpo9M@/zyCEFw)

Not the shortest Python solution but an alternative approach (1 indexed).

Shorter but not very interesting:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 34 bytes

```python
lambda i:int("303232332323"[i])+28
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHTKjOvREPJ2MDYCAjBhFJ0ZqymtpHF/4IioJxCmoahJheMaYRgGiOYJgimKYJphmCaI5gWCKYlgmlogMRGss/QSPM/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
^o$
x
o{7}|oo

^
31*
__x|_o
```

Explanation:

```
^o$      match input equal to "o"
x        replace it with x
o{7}|oo  match 7 or 2 "o"s, whichever the regex engine prefers
         replace them with nothing (this happens to compute a%7%2)
^        match the beginning of string
31*      and replace it with 31 times the default character (_)
__x|_o   match __x or _o literally
         and erase them (that is, "x" means "erase two _" and "o" means "erase one _")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvqpHA9T8uX4Wrgiu/2ry2Jj@fiyuOy9hQiys@vqImPp/r/3@ufK58EAJjCAElYRScRjCQWMjMfAA)

Comment: You can remove the `}` to save a byte ([relevant part of the docs](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language#a-note-on-unmatched-brackets) EDIT: or maybe not, seems like an undocumented feature).

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, though I'm pretty sure that section refers to groupings when substituting, not the patterns themselves, so this is probably a different feature.

Comment: Hmm good point.. I just noticed it works without the closing bracket, and was looking for the relevant docs. Maybe it's undocumented/hidden. :)

Comment: For some reason it also doesn't seem to work with normal human circular `()` parentheses. Maybe that's a .NET regex "feature"?

Comment: No, [it doesn't seem to work in .NET C#](https://tio.run/##fczBCoJAEIDhe08x7EUFUzpEUOmtTp008CzLZAu2u@zslhG@epsaQqdOAzP/N5yWnIT3Ryf5nqwRsonhO3O4QAaU5QXqtuYYUszUa9OzmLFot7jXBoTUzg6RxAeUEwoDFcSr9XCvjLB4EhLD2U/1z49oB2kKlbBX4K2iQUP/l81qZspZ799KW6Ek@dRtyydZvCVn7GxSYOPa2hw6bZBoLMYVdh8). Ah well.. PS: You forgot to update your byte-count in the title.

Comment: The change Kevin suggested doesn't appear to produce the correct output. I believe it is trying to match a literal `{` in that case. However, you can save a byte by doing `o{7}|oo` instead of two replacements.

Comment: Huh; I'm not sure why haven't I tried that (for some reason I assumed it is likely to produce incorrect results, but haven't actually tried it).

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 46 bytes

```
func[m][b:(a: to now[1 m 1])+ 31 b/4: 1 b - a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcUxCgIxEAXQ3lN8tlJEQtTGOYbtMEV2M0FhMwmbLOLpo695m8bx1MhySDTSbgtn4ZmOgdALrHzYI8PL6Yybx@zuhH@4IMjYtGroMPgruG5v61xDRPu2rtmtZQmrulysv5ojwwMTTUgwkfED)

A verbose solution that literally calculates the number of days in the given month (28 for february - year 1 AD)

### Explanation:

```
Red[]
f: func[m][
    a: to now [1 m 1]   ; make a date dd-mm-yyyy (1st of the "month" year 1 AD)
    b: a + 31           ; add 31 days to it
    b/4: 1              ; and go back to the 1st day of the new month
    b - a               ; subtract the initial date from the new one 
]
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @Xcali it can be even shorter:

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 35 bytes

```perl
$_=substr"3128".3130313031x2,$_*2,2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ra4NKm4pEjJ2NDIQknP2NDYAIIrjHRU4rWMdIz@/zf8l19QkpmfV/xftwAA)

As suggested by @manatwork this can be shortened substantial:

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 39 bytes

```perl
("3128".3130313031x2)=~/(..){$_}/;$_=$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/J2NDIwtjQ2ACK4Swl2zp9DT09zWqV@Fp9a5V4WxXD//@N/uUXlGTm5xX/1y0AAA)

<s>Perl (And because I like regex, a first humble attempt):</s>

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 60 bytes

```perl
print $1 if "312831303130313130313031" =~ /(..){$ARGV[0]}/g;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvREHFUCEzTUHJ2NDIwtjQ2ACK4SwlBds6BX0NPT3NahXHIPewaIPYWv106////xsBAA)

Invoke via `perl -e` and user supplied input, e.g. `2` for the month, at command line argument with index 0.

Comment: 1) None of the spaces are needed. 2) Is shorter without `if`: just do the pattern matching then `print` in separate statements. 3) Is shorter to get the month number as input. 4) If taking input, is shorter to automate it using `-p` switch. 5) No need for the `g` modifier. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/J2NDIwtjQ2ACK4Swl2zp9DT09zWqV@Fp9a5V4WxXD//@N/uUXlGTm5xX/1y0AAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: That's a substantial truncation.

Comment: A bit shorter if you repeat the common part of the string: `("3128".3130313031x2)`.

Comment: Even shorter if you use `substr` and 0-index: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ra4NKm4pEjJ2NDIQknP2NDYAIIrjHRU4rWMdIz@/zf8l19QkpmfV/xftwAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks @Xcali I incorporated the changes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

Not in any way clever, but there you go. Pretty much checks all the non-31-day months and if it isn't any of them it falls back on 31.

```
f 2=28;f m|elem m[4,6,9,11]=30;f _=31
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchBCsIwEAXQ/T9FFi4UQugktbZITiIig05oMInSVNx49yi@5Zu53iWlljkWH8sqC19XtVGvkmKRajI/t3V@vE0wi/BtZ/7dgrLejseg8keSZJVPvR70pInO3nW/v3hHrREsHHrsMeCAEROoAxHIfgE)

Comment: [27 bytes, with 0-indexing](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZZ1ucWliampecqpKbWKBRUJSZV6KXphltoKdnaBj7P03B0NbIwjpNIdfW2FA3Nz9FIVfBPAFIJxj9/w8A)

Comment: @UnrelatedString, go ahead and post as your own answer if you want. I think it's less a revision of my answer than a completely new one.

Answer (score 3):

### Excel, 29 bytes

```
=DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(0,B1,1),0))
```

Where `B1` is the month number (1-based).

Comment: Porting @Adam's formula is shorter at 27 bytes: `=31-(A1=1)-MOD(MOD(A1,7),2)`

Answer (score 3):

## z80 Machine Code, 13 bytes

```
47 1F 1F 1F A8 E6 01 05 10 01 3D C6 30
```

Takes input (starting at 1) in the A register and stores output in the same register. This was manually assembled from the ez80 manual and is not yet tested, therefore it might contain some mistakes.

**Explanation:**

```
47        ld b, a         ; Copy the value to the B register
1F 1F 1F  rra   (3 times) ; \ Set A to ((A >> 3) ^ B) & 1, which is
A8        xor a, b        ; | equal to 1 on all months with 31 days
E6 01     and a, 1        ; / 
05        dec b           ; \ Decrement the B register twice and skip the next instruction if 
10 01     djnz $+3        ; / the resulting value is not zero (if the month is not february)
3D        dec a           ; Decrement A (if february)
C6 30     add a, 30       ; Add 30 to A
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C++ (g++)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <del>60</del> <del>54</del> <del>47</del> 40 bytes

1-indexed. f(2)==29.

```
int f(int n){return(n^n/8)%2-(n==2)+30;}
```

Solution from k-map, which simplified to A=w+x+z and B=zw'+z'w. A was negated and became a subtraction.

```
int f(int n){      //N is a 4-digit binary number wxyz.
return (n^n/8) %2  //Add 1 if (w XOR z)
     - (n==2)      //Subtract 1 if !(w OR x OR z), which simplifies to (w'x'z'),
                   //which is only satisfied when N is 0000 or 0010.
                   //Since n is never 0, this condition is only satisfied when n==2.
     + 30;         //Add 30, the base month length.
}
```

At first I tried adding 1 or 2 instead of 1 or 1, but my solution was 87 bytes (if I remember correctly). I tried that with 0-indexing and 1-indexing, but they ended up being the exact same length.

47 bytes: `int f(int n){return(n/8|n/4|n)%2+(n^n/8)%2+29;}`

54 bytes: `int f(int n){return((n>>3|n>>2|n)&1)+((n^n>>3)&1)+29;}`

60 bytes: `int f(int n){return(n>>3&1|n>>2&1|n&1)+((n&1)^(n>>3&1))+29;}`

Edit: Thanks to Herman L. for the improvement to 54 bytes, I'm glad someone found my approach interesting even though it's clearly not the shortest!

Edit 2: Thank you to ceilingcat for the improvement to 47 bytes. This uses division instead of bit shifting, which saves one byte in each of three places. It also replaces `&1` with `%2` in two places. Both of these functionally return the last byte of the integer, but the modulo operator has precedence over addition. This means that two pairs of parentheses can be removed, saving four bytes. In total, by mixing arithmetic and bitwise operators, ceilingcat managed to improve the answer by seven bytes!

Edit 3: Another improvement by ceilingcat brings it down six bytes by doing bitwise comparison with 13, `-!(n&13)`. Since this is only true in one case, simplified to an equality check.

Comment: Welcome to CG&CC!

Comment: A few bytes can be saved by reordering the operators: `int f(int n){return((n>>3|n>>2|n)&1)+((n^n>>3)&1)+29;}`

Comment: @HermanL Thank you, it looks so obvious now that you point that out! I guess I need more practice with bitwise operators.

Comment: @ceilingcat Great idea! I wouldn't have thought to use `/`, since I was focussed on bitwise operators.

Comment: @ceilingcat Nice! Got it down to 40 and updated the answer. Good idea with the subtraction.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, 23 bytes

```
n=>15662007>>~-n*2&3|28
```

This is utilizing a binary map 15662007 which is

```
111011101111101110110111
11.10.11.10.11.11.10.11.10.11.01.11
 3. 2. 3. 2. 3. 3. 2. 3. 2. 3. 1. 3
```

You just add each item to 28 and see that it provides a proper mapping to each month.

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-rr`, <s>17</s> <s>16</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
$:&1=-&7%2%-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N/@@QZlij/F9exUrN0FZXzVzVSFX3/7FJh/Y7pB2b9N/wv25REQA)

Simply a port of Adams APL answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```ruby
->n{31-n%7%2-2[n]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6v2thQN0/VXNVI1yg6L7b2v6GRXklmbmpxdU1FTYFCdIVOWnRFLFAcAA)

0-based, basically the same formula as Adam, adapted to ruby.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
%7Ḃ31__1⁼$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/V/OGOJmPD@HjDR417VP4bGj3cse1w@6OmNZH/AQ)

Pretty much just a translation of Adám and Kevin Cruijssen's APL and 05ab1e answers, respectively. There's probably some way I could cut out the `$`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>10</strike> 8 bytes

0-indexed, February is 29.

```
C@.""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/39lBT0lW/uPijjal//@NAQ) TIO doesn't seem to like the UTF-8 conjoined character, but it works in the official interpreter. Consider TIO a glorified pastebin for this.

Previous version, 10 bytes:

```
C@."Îï»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/39lBT0lGnvlw3@H1h3Yr/f9vCAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 19 bytes

```
(31-0 2 0,#:330){~]
```

For fun, here's a J translation of Adam's APL answer (also 12 bytes):

```
31-1&=+2|7&|
```

Jonah's comment saves another 4 bytes, due to:

1. better use of J's hook: `({...)` instead of `(...{~])`
2. better choice of starting binary values, adjusting the arithmetic as necessary (`30+1 _1,...` rather than `31-0 2 0,...`):

```
| expr    | result               |
|---------|----------------------|
| 0,#:330 | 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0  |
| #:693   | 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1  |
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuo2CgYAXEunoKzkE@bv81jA11DRSMFAx0lK2MjQ00q@ti/2tycaUmZ@QrpCkYwBiGMIYRjJGpZ2j0HwA)

Comment: I came up with a similar [15 byte](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/q40NtA0V4g11lK0czCyN/2tycaUmZ@QraOjoKaRpKmTqGRr9BwA "J – Try It Online") approach (`{30+1 _1,#:@693`), but it can still be beaten by translating Adam's solution directly into J.

Comment: Nice. I tried to translate Adam's to J but failed to make it shorter, probably because I don't quite grok APL yet.

Comment: Aha, got it: `31-1&=+2|7&|` 
Thanks!

Comment: That's the one.  Nice!

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL 61 bytes

```
declare @ int set @=2print DAY(EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(1,@,1)))
```

40 bytes if we put the input directly to the query:

```
print DAY(EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(1,2,1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
--31%%Q7 2q1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1fX2FBVNdBcwajQ8P9/EwA)

Port of [@Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195887/90146)'s answer

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>22</strike>  18 bytes

```
-+30@+*4U2t*3U2Qq2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1fb2MBBW8sk1KhEyzjUKLDQ6P9/QyMA)

Uses 1-indexed months and 29 as February. Theres probably a more refined solution somewhere
Saved 4 bytes by using U2 instead of ,Z1 and replacing the logic with -1 if input is 2

### How it works

```
-+30@+*4U2t*3U2Qq2
 +30               - 30 plus...
    @          Q   - The index Q=input
     +*4U2         - Of 4 times the list [0,1] -> [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
          t*3U2    - Plus 3 times the list [0,1] minus the first element
-               q2 - Minus [2 == input], with input added implicitly
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 27 bytes

-3 bytes thx to Jo King for putting all into a tertiary statement.

```
Fn.new{|x|1==x?28:31-x%7%2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkKhgq/DfLU8vL7W8uqaixtDWtsLeyMLK2FC3QtVc1aj2f3BlcUlqrl55UWZJqkaiXnJiTo6GgabmfwA)

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 35 bytes

-4 bytes thx 2 Jo King for noticing that `.bytes[x]` would work.

```
Fn.new{|x|" ".bytes[x]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkKhgq/DfLU8vL7W8uqaiRklBXkZeDgjBhJJeUmVJanF0RWzt/@DK4pLUXL3yosySVI1EveTEnBwNI03N/wA)

Comment: For the first, you can move it all into the ternary statment for [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkKhgq/DfLU8vL7W8uqaixtDWtsLeyMLK2FC3QtVc1aj2f3BlcUlqrl55UWZJqkaiXnJiTo6GgabmfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 22 bytes

```c
f(n){n=31-n%7%2-!~-n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcg7DoQgEADQnlOwJCQzURI/xRazHsagmCmcNYgVYa/O6iufd5v3tQYQzDKNvRP7toN7/ZxQqSxJ7zOLBswqfCM8wVNH/OkH4qbBfMT7Ahi7mDYAI9JxpROMQSoqrumKojtSpf4B)

Stealing from @Arnaulds / @Adám

---

<s>29</s>  [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9No0KzusJWSV5GXg4IwYRSdEWsde3/zLwShdzEzDwFDc1qrrT8Ig2QQKatgXWmjaGRdaa2tmZ1QRFQLE1DSTVFSSdNI1NT07qgtKRYQ0lJ07qWqyi1pLQoT8HAmqv2PwA)

```c
f(x){x=""[x];}
```

Port of @Embodiment of Ignorance answer

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 28 bytes

```cs
x=>DateTime.DaysInMonth(1,x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY4xC8IwFIT3/IqMCWqhrrEuiiLYScE5xld9kL5oXioV8bfXLIIIDsdxd99wjieO3dAx0lnuHpygNeI7FYvgPbiEgfj/UqyBIKL7IbZINyPEtTt6dNJ5yyyvMZyjbeXzU3OyKds94EnWFknpvK06cjOkNM6aN9XQV/OlTbDHFoqlffCG6kDpospxrwfThKgyKLEqDc6qcmpwNNJykZ8FD8UhYoL8BVSjUGsjXuI1vAE)

Comment: This is exactly the old revision of Embodiment's C# answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/195901/revisions :(

Comment: Ohh, I didn't see it in the answers so I assumed no one had posted this yet

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 27 bytes

```hs
f 1=28;f m=31-mod m 7`mod`2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZZ5ubWOCrUVCUmVeil6YZbaCnZ2gY@z9NwdDWyMI6TSHX1thQNzc/RSFXwTwBSCcY/f8PAA)

0-indexed. Handles February the same way that Andrew Ray's answer does, but otherwise uses the mod-7-mod-2 approach.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# .NET](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 98 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){System.Console.Write((int)" "[int.Parse(a[0])]);}}
```

[Try Online](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS5O/v8/OSexuFghoLq4JLEkM1mhLD8zRcE3MTNPo7ikKDMvPTo2UbM6uLK4JDVXzzk/rzg/J1UvvCizJFVDIzOvRFNJQV5GXg4IwYRSNFBMLyCxqDhVIzHaIFYzVtO6tvb///@mAA) 
Uses Ascii control characters (RS, US and FS) and gets their absolute character value.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 18 bytes

```
31-(Ans=1)-2fPart(3.5fPart(Ans/7
```

Takes input in `Ans` as a 0-indexed month. Returns 29 for February.

#### 18 bytes

```
101+Ans(Ans≠11
dbd(Ans,Ans+1
```

Alternative solution using a different approach. Takes input in `Ans` as a 0-indexed month. Returns 29 for February.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
7%ɗ$ḅ+31_
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPTclMjUlQzklOTclMjQlRTElQjglODUlMkIzMV8mZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0wJTBBMSUwQTIlMEEzJTBBNCUwQTUlMEE2JTBBNyUwQTglMEE5JTBBMTAlMEExMSZmbGFncz1W)

Port of Adám's APL answer.

##### Explanation

```python
7%ɗ$ḅ+31_  # Implicit input
      31_  # 31 - (
7%ɗ        #   (input % 7 % 2)
     +     #   +
   $ḅ      #   (input == 1)
           # )
           # Implicit output
```