# Write the date in abbreviated Latin

Tags: code-golf, date, roman-numerals

*Inspired by [How do you write dates in Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/how-do-you-write-dates-in-latin)*

### Challenge

Given a month-and-day date, output that date in abbreviated Latin, as explained below.

### Input

Input is flexible, following conventions from other [date](/questions/tagged/date) and [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) challenges. You may choose to:

- Take a date in mm/dd or dd/mm format or two separate month,day arguments;
- Take a date in your language's date format;
- Take an integer in interval [0, 364] corresponding to a day in the year;
- Take some other reasonable input that can encode all 365 days of the year;
- Take no user input but output the current day's date;
- Take no input and output all 365 days of the year in order;

Importantly, you only need to care about the month and day, not about the year, and you can assume that the year is not a leap year.

### Output

Output is the date in abbreviated Latin, as specified in this section in BNF, and as explained more verbosely in the next section.

```
<output> ::= <delay> <event> <month>
<event> ::= "Kal" | "Non" | "Eid"
<month> ::= "Ian" | "Feb" | "Mar" | "Apr" | "Mai" | "Iun" | "Iul" | "Aug" | "Sep" | "Oct" | "Nov" | "Dec"
<delay> ::= "" | <one-day-delay> | <n-days-delay>
<one-day-delay> ::= "prid"
<n-day-delay> ::= "a d" <roman-numeral>
<roman-numeral> ::= "III" | "IV" | "V" | "VI" | "VII" | "VIII" | "IX" | "X" | "XI" | "XII" | "XIII" | "XIV" | "XV" | "XVI" | "XVII" | "XVIII" | "XIX"
```

### How do you write dates in abbreviated Latin?

*Adapted from [How do you write dates in Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/how-do-you-write-dates-in-latin)*

There are 36 special days in the year.

- A date which is a special day is encoded by giving the name of that special day;
- A date which is just before a special day is encoded by writing `prid` followed by the name of that special day;
- Another day is encoded by writing `a d` followed by the number of days between that date and the next special day, **counting inclusively**, using Roman numerals, followed by the name of that special day.

Counting inclusively, there are for instance 3 days between January 3rd and January 5th.

The Roman counting system is oddly inclusive to modern taste. Whenever we would say that something is n days earlier, the Romans would have said n+1. The day just before the special day is two days before it (we'd say one day) and uses `prid` instead of numbering, so the unnamed days start their numbering at 3.

The 36 special days are:

- The Kalendae, first day of the month: `01/01, 02/01, ..., 12/01`, written `Kal <month>`, respectively: `Kal Ian`, `Kal Feb`, `Kal Mar`, `Kal Apr`, `Kal Mai`, `Kal Iun`, `Kal Iul`, `Kal Aug`, `Kal Sep`, `Kal Oct`, `Kal Nov`, `Kal Dec`;
- The Nonae, 5th or 7th day of the month: `01/05, 02/05, 03/07, 04/05, 05/07, 06/05, 07/07, 08/05, 09/05, 10/07, 11/05, 12/05`, written `Non <month>`, respectively: `Non Ian, Non Feb, Non Mar, Non Apr, Non Mai, Non Iun, Non Iul, Non Aug, Non Sep, Non Oct, Non Nov, Non Dec`;
- The Ides, 13th or 15th day of the month: `01/13, 02/13, 03/15, 04/13, 05/15, 06/13, 07/15, 08/13, 09/13, 10/15, 11/13, 12/13`, written `Eid <month>`, respectively: `Eid Ian, Eid Feb, Eid Mar, Eid Apr, Eid Mai, Eid Iun, Eid Iul, Eid Aug, Eid Sep, Eid Oct, Eid Nov, Eid Dec`.

Note the Nonae and Ides come two days later in the four months of March, May, July and October.

Because of these rules, only Roman numerals between 3 and 19 are required.

### Test cases

```
mm/dd  -->  abbrev. Lat.

01/01  -->  Kal Ian
01/02  -->  a d IV Non Ian
01/03  -->  a d III Non Ian
01/04  -->  prid Non Ian
01/05  -->  Non Ian
02/02  -->  a d IV Non Feb
02/27  -->  a d III Kal Mar
02/28  -->  prid Kal Mar
03/01  -->  Kal Mar
03/02  -->  a d VI Non Mar
04/02  -->  a d IV Non Apr
05/02  -->  a d VI Non Mai
06/02  -->  a d IV Non Iun
07/02  -->  a d VI Non Iul
08/02  -->  a d IV Non Aug
08/05  -->  Non Aug
09/02  -->  a d IV Non Sep
10/02  -->  a d VI Non Oct
10/15  -->  Eid Oct
10/12  -->  a d IV Eid Oct
10/13  -->  a d III Eid Oct
10/14  -->  prid Eid Oct
10/17  -->  a d XVI Kal Nov
11/02  -->  a d IV Non Nov
12/02  -->  a d IV Non Dec
12/14  -->  a d XIX Kal Ian
12/30  -->  a d III Kal Ian
12/31  -->  prid Kal Ian
```

### Rules

- This is code-golf, the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Presumably 31st of December is prid Kal Ian? Might be a good test case.

Comment: @Neil Correct; added.

Comment: If the input really is flexible, can we just take the month and the day as two separate arguments?

Comment: I suggest `<delay> ::= "" | <one-day-delay> | <n-days-delay>`

Comment: @matteo_c You are absolutely right!

Comment: @Arnauld Yes you can, I've edited to make it even more explicit

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing `[0, 354]` should be `[0, 364]`?

Comment: @psmears Are you implying I don't know how many days are in a year?! Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 163 bytes

```
Ｆ³⁶⁵⊞υωＦ¹⁹Ｆ¹²Ｆ³§≔υ⁺⁺Ｉ§⪪”)¶Ｏ↥…⊞H₂；≦'⪫⦃π0S｜”³κ∧λ⊗⁻×⁴λ∨№1358Ｉκ²ι⪫Φ⟦×‹ι¹⁷a d§⪪”{⧴,π⁶δυＷ≦χVM⪫mSＤfZ<hνＨm¬⍘ψc⎇⊖ＭlR5ρν” ι§⪪KalNonEid³λ§⪪”>-b∧⊖αθ?｜¬Ｙ≔⁼IΦ«wS▷ＮAº⁸Fω&↗”³κ⟧μ υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFdS8MwFH33V1z6lECFpmn3wZ7K5iDq5mAyCuJD1sYtmKUlbab/vibZFNTAOdybe@5HbqojN1XD1TC8NQYQHeUYNrY7IhvDB57dhFsyxXAx0qtBMRRdJw@66JmuxaeXb5TtUKA573r0Hdm2SvYoSghNMpKMU5KkhFIyomSapWme5nk6GXk/G0cxUBzDO3ZU6BqpGBaN3StRo5XUrvCzPIkOZTEop3gyaN5Y7WoTmk9cbmgbklPsTwzS4b6RGi2l6oVBL5cCj6LrkIyBjF084lBHvuHveUtWQrljjAX25AAl8/B@AJTgZEG1C4AdOIX3WyNrcENFEF0H@dPggat1o@9kfX21@i9Ziv2Km6I1Ky6Z1cyqwh62on2q@nVzXoiKcf2zs9cYTvjSz/3bxki3GYtnwzDcntUX) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs all 365 days. Explanation:

```
Ｆ³⁶⁵⊞υω
```

Allocate an array of 365 days so that cyclic indexing will fill in some of the January values.

```
Ｆ¹⁹
```

Start from `a d XIX Kal Feb...a d XIX Kal Ian` and work forward to `Kal Feb...Kal Ian`.

```
Ｆ¹²
```

Loop from `Feb` to `Ian`. (This avoids a negative number below.)

```
Ｆ³
```

Loop over `Kal`, `Non` and `Eid`.

```
§≔υ⁺⁺Ｉ§⪪”...”³κ∧λ⊗⁻×⁴λ∨№1358Ｉκ²ι
```

Calculate the day of year that this day would be (if it existed).

```
⪫Φ⟦×‹ι¹⁷a d§⪪”...” ι§⪪KalNonEid³λ§⪪”...”³κ⟧μ
```

Overwrite it with the name of this day, made up of four optional parts: `a d`, the day number (or `prid`), the special day, and the month, joined with a space (which is at the end of the above line).

```
υ
```

Output all of the days of the year.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>268 ... 262</s>  252 bytes

Expects `(month)(day)`.

```javascript
m=>d=>([t=0,q=2384>>m&2^4,q+8,m-2?~-m%1.7^31:28].every(k=>(n=k+1-d)<0&&++t,A="KalNonEidIanFebMarAprMaiIunIulAugSepOctNovDecIanI II III IV V VI VII VIII IX  ".match(/[IVX]* |.../g))|n?n-1?"a d "+(n>8?"X":"")+A[n%10+16]:"prid ":"")+A[t%3]+" "+A[m+=2^t>2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdjppAFMfvfYqTSdSZHb4G3C7RAjHpNiHNbi@aGBMWGwpo7fLhApo03fYJmvSml@179Hn2BfoI9uBiFC3MkGF@/zlzvj4Fm6AMi@WqkrM8irdza5tadmTZ1KssTXqwdMMc2Hba02cD6YGbUirrzjc57QrlamaIoW76SryJi8/0Hs9k1j0XcsRear0e55U0tsibILnNs@tl5AbZ6/jDTVCMV8VNsHTXmbtOxuvFu3j1Nqxu882rOESNC249cE4AXxfHbuLGFIAoaVCFH6nquZOpfwGPiqKoC8YeMyeThUMCiIBwmtmmQ6ZkSAjjYy/rCo2LF/6QrIol8ma76ho@Jygfeym39Fll6/525HXwFk2omgCQZRsAAwD0i0h7oDegvgudxOja3Djm6PeZYNAIdt6c0cuGtoGu6lcndmvHMJ0HgXlst02NdjwHYLYvxHo8A6GpYg@weIAlOoCTDJzx0wycCVoZOKPHgU4nz4FifzQC/XB8J8C2aJUIBYb2n1S1BOI0VTXt@B1lnhfXATZYCZYNX1CexBV48F6CVIJIgnxdgQ8WlPtG1Bx6F3F2t180hqlywVRW31c/RYz2YE55yiiP2Ai3wzwr8yRWknxBS6VMlmFMNQkuGXAggCYILupz9W@9pjsj1s4DB/p///x4@vUTv30YQv/p9/c@Q7tf2Wj7Dw)

#### Algorithm

The `every()` loop looks for the first 0-indexed special day that is greater than or equal to \$d-1\$.

Once completed:

- The number of days before the next special day is loaded in \$n\in[0\dots18]\$.
- The type of the special day is loaded in \$t\in[0\dots3]\$:

  - \$t=0\$ → first day of the current month
  - \$t=1\$ → Nonae
  - \$t=2\$ → Ides
  - \$t=3\$ → first day of the next month

#### Formulas

- `q = 2384 >> m & 2 ^ 4` gives the 0-indexed day of the Nonae for month \$m\$ (either \$4\$ or \$6\$).
- `q + 8` gives the 0-indexed day of the Ides for month \$m\$ (either \$12\$ or \$14\$).
- `~-m % 1.7 ^ 31` gives the number of days in month \$m\$, except for February which is processed separately. I first used this decimal remainder trick in [one of my solutions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195890/58563) to [this other challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/195884/58563).

#### Lookup string

Most substrings are stored into a single lookup string:

```javascript
"KalNonEidIanFebMarAprMaiIunIulAugSepOctNovDecIanI II III IV V VI VII VIII IX  "
 \_______/\_____________________________________/\____________________________/
  special                 months                     Roman numeral suffixes
   days         (wrapping from Dec to Ian)           (followed by a space)
```

which is split with the following regular expression:

```javascript
/[IVX]* |.../g  // either a Roman numeral suffix followed by a space
                // or 3 characters
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 125 bytes

```
“Y8ṁ`yƈʋIƊĠSṖḶ⁾İ2’ṃ“XVI ”Ḳ“a d ”;Ɱ““prid”;
“-gBƥ]ṢḲ@’b6s2+“¢Ñ‘j€8FRUị¢ṭ€"“¡Qḟ8i,ȷıƊḳė¦øsÑNpq>ė7 “¢Zıƒ>ɠ’ṃØas€3ŒtƊŒpṙ1¤Ẏ⁸ịṚ¹ƇK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xIi4c7GxMqj3Wc6vY81nVkQfDDndMe7tj2qHHfkQ1GjxpmPtzZDFQVEeap8Khh7sMdm4CcRIUUEMf60cZ1QB4QFRRlpoAEuIBs3XSnY0tjH@5cBFTrANSfZFZspA0UP7To8MRHDTOyHjWtsXALCn24u/vQooc71wK5SiDZhYEPd8y3yNQ5sf3IxmNdD3dsPjL90LLDO4oPT/QrKLQ7Mt1cAWxGFFB2kt3JBRCHHZ6RWAw0wPjopJJjXUcnFTzcOdPw0JKHu/oeNe4AWvBw56xDO4@1e/@3BupV0LUDO/pwO5exmSnQh4fbgVoj/wMA)

A pair of links called as a monad, taking an integer from 0 to 364 and returning a string representing the relevant date. (Technically will also work for numbers outside that range since it uses a modular index into a list of all 365 possibilities.)

### Explanation

```
“Y8ṁ`yƈʋIƊĠSṖḶ⁾İ2’ṃ“XVI ”Ḳ“a d ”;Ɱ““prid”;                                          # ‎⁡Helper link: called as a nilad, generates the delay parts of the date
“Y8ṁ`yƈʋIƊĠSṖḶ⁾İ2’                                                                  # ‎⁢Base 250 integer 84034955351979905312914389471555862301
                  ṃ“XVI ”                                                           # ‎⁣Base decompress into "XVI "
                         Ḳ                                                          # ‎⁤Split on spaces
                          “a d ”;Ɱ                                                  # ‎⁢⁡Prepend each with "a d "
                                  ““prid”;                                          # ‎⁢⁢Prepend an empty string and then "prid"
‎⁢⁣
“-gBƥ]ṢḲ@’b6s2+“¢Ñ‘j€8FRUị¢ṭ€"“¡Qḟ8i,ȷıƊḳė¦øsÑNpq>ė7 “¢Zıƒ>ɠ’ṃØas€3ŒtƊŒpṙ1¤Ẏ⁸ịṚ¹ƇK  # ‎⁢⁤Main link: takes an integer and returns a string representing the date
“-gBƥ]ṢḲ@’                                                                          # ‎⁣⁡Base 250 integer 2833073888199044565
          b6                                                                        # ‎⁣⁢Convert to base 6
            s2                                                                      # ‎⁣⁣Split into pieces of length 2
              +“¢Ñ‘                                                                 # ‎⁣⁤Add 1 to the first member of each sublist and 16 to the second
                   j€8                                                              # ‎⁤⁡Join each with 8
                      F                                                             # ‎⁤⁢Flatten
                       R                                                            # ‎⁤⁣Ranges from 1..z for each z in this list
                        U                                                           # ‎⁤⁤Reverse each range
                         ị¢                                                         # ‎⁢⁡⁡Index into the helper link
                           ṭ€"                                            ¤         # ‎⁢⁡⁢Tag each member of each of the sublists of strings onto the corresponding sublist from the following:
                              “¡Qḟ8i,ȷıƊḳė¦øsÑNpq>ė7 “¢Zıƒ>ɠ’                       # ‎⁢⁡⁣Base 250 integers 302811639626768516702588802453858478870563499076533, 2309009953410
                                                                     Ɗ              # ‎⁢⁡⁤Following as a monad (used to avoid having to have ¤ after each of the nilads in the following)
                                                             ṃØa                    # ‎⁢⁢⁡- Base decompress into lowercase letters
                                                                s€3                 # ‎⁢⁢⁢- Split each into pieces length 3
                                                                   Œt               # ‎⁢⁢⁣- Convert to title case
                                                                      Œp            # ‎⁢⁢⁤Cartesian product
                                                                        ṙ1          # ‎⁢⁣⁡Rotate left one (moves Ian Kal to the end)
                                                                           Ẏ        # ‎⁢⁣⁢Join outer lists (after this step we have all 365 dates but with their component pieces in the wrong order and not yet joined with spaces)
                                                                            ⁸ị      # ‎⁢⁣⁣Index the main link’s argument into this
                                                                              Ṛ     # ‎⁢⁣⁤Reverse
                                                                               ¹Ƈ   # ‎⁢⁤⁡Keep only those that are non-empty (removes the space from before the exact special dates)
                                                                                 K  # ‎⁢⁤⁢Join with spaces
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).